# SQL missing if statement

Tags: sql, if-statement

Kindly help. I have below columns in mytable: a,b,c,d,e, g, h

I want to do some processing to get only 3 columns(a, price and h)

```
select a, if a = b and d = e then g/h as price
else
if a = d then g/100 as price
else
h/100 as price
if price = 0
then
price = 0.1,
h
from my table
```

---

thanks all but i still get 'invalid number of arguments. below is my SQL

select TICKETID AS "BLO",

case when (NOTIONAL_CURRENCY = BASE_CURRENCY AND  PREMIUM_CURRENCY = TERM_CURRENCY)
                   THEN 
                         round((TERM_MARKET_PRICE/NOTIONAL),9)
 else

```
 case

  when (NOTIONAL_CURRENCY = PREMIUM_CURRENCY) 
               THEN
                     round((BASE_MARKET_PRICE_PERCENT/100),9)
      else

 round((TERM_MARKET_PRICE_PERCENT/100),9)

   else .1 end
```

END as "PRICE"

, TERM_CURRENCY "CURRENCY"

FROM DBAPP.SD_STAGE

Comment: Where does this SQL come from? It doesn't look like SQL all that much.

Comment: So what is the *problem* here?

Comment: Which RDBMS? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? ...?

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for conditionals in SQL is

```
CASE WHEN <condition> THEN a ELSE b END CASE
```

Your select can be written as:

```
select a, 
       case when (case when a = b and d = e and h > 0 then g/h
            when a = d then g/100 
            else  h/100
            end case) = 0 then .1 
       else (case when a = b and d = e then g/h
            when a = d then g/100 
            else  h/100
            end case) 
       end case  as price,
       h
from my table
```

simplified:

```
select a, 
       case when a = b and d = e and h > 0 and g > 0 then g/h
            when a = d and g > 0 then g/100 
            when h > 0 then h/100
            else 0.1
       end case  as price,
       h
from my table
```

Answer (score 1):

May be simpler in some SQL varieties, but to cover them all you can just nest a `CASE`;

```
SELECT a, CASE
          WHEN a = b AND d = e THEN CASE WHEN g=0 THEN 0.1 ELSE g/h   END 
          WHEN a = d           THEN CASE WHEN g=0 THEN 0.1 ELSE g/100 END
          ELSE                      CASE WHEN h=0 THEN 0.1 ELSE h/100 END            
          END price, h
FROM  my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Use case instead of if, it will do what you want.

e.g. something like `select a, case when a = b and d = e then g/h else case when a = d then g/100 else h/100 else .1 end else .1 end as price from my_table`

Comment: thanks all but i still get 'invalid number of arguments. below is my SQL

select TICKETID AS "BLO", 

case when (NOTIONAL_CURRENCY = BASE_CURRENCY AND PREMIUM_CURRENCY = TERM_CURRENCY) THEN round((TERM_MARKET_PRICE/NOTIONAL),9) else
 case

  when (NOTIONAL_CURRENCY = PREMIUM_CURRENCY) 
               THEN
                     round((BASE_MARKET_PRICE_PERCENT/100),9)
      else

 round((TERM_MARKET_PRICE_PERCENT/100),9)

   else .1 end 
 END as "PRICE"

, TERM_CURRENCY "CURRENCY"

FROM DBAPP.SD_STAGE

Comment: The error that I see is that in my example, I ended the inner case statement first, then had the else for the outer case and then the end for the outer case  You have the two end statements right together.  It needs to be else end else end, you have else else end end That might not be the only error but lets fix that and then see if there is something else.